# what is the work of EL in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have been using **JSF2** for almost one year and (maybe due to lack of experience or great level of abstraction in JSF MVC component model) yet not clearly know about details on flow of control in **JSF**.

- how a `h:inputText` passes its data to backing bean and vice-verse and how getter and setters are involved in this process?
- how Ajax work with JSF Validators?

and main question

- how EL works in JSF

Really very eager to know how all these work done in which sequence.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Whatever his experience . Question makes sense .. !! :)

Comment: @babel Ok Brother Suppose if i am working in Java Past 1year and then ask what is OOPS concept what will be your reaction? Also this site not provide any tutorial or bunch of teachers who can teach us..Here someone can guide us if we fail in our effort.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi how passing the values from view to model is to bind it with value attribute of <h:inputText> tag with backing bean varialble ? is not my question. Question is that how a variable  in bean can be bind with a html tag attribute ?

Comment: Try google brother http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: just take an example of jsp pages ....there we define the name attribute for request.getParameter in servlet to get values from it ......but nothing is here in JSF.....what is the abstraction on implementation of this mechanism?

Comment: Beans are not directly bound to html inputs. That is technically impossible. It all happens via request parameters to. Just look at the network tab of your browser developer tool. And then on the server the request parameters are processed and the data is put in the corresponding bean via the setter. Want more detail? Run your app in a debugger and set some breakpoints here and there… and ajax or non-ajax is irrelevant for validators

Comment: @SubodhJoshi  thanks for the link,revealed some of the doubts. And I really couldn't get into the roots of the technology just because of project completion pressure and lot more....

Comment: No issue when ever you get time please read @BaluC http://balusc.blogspot.in/